# HTMLAgilityPack - Unable to download multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to download files from a html table by iterating through the 'a' tags and downloading their contents.

```
    protected void ClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(InputTextBox.Text); //Value of inputTextBox.Text is same as website variable below

        var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

        string website = "https://test.website.co.uk/web/stuff/0010/";
        string test = @"C:\Test";



        if (aTags != null)
        {

            foreach (var aTag in aTags)
            {




                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile(website += aTag.InnerHtml, test += aTag.InnerHtml);


            }
        }
    }
```

I have tested extensively. Hardcoding exact file paths works just fine. However when I try to download in bulk it throws an exception 'A required priviledge is not held by the client'. I don't believe the issue to be permissions related as I can download single files when hardcoding variables. I havealso tried skipping the first few nodes which are not files to download but merely headers with 'a' tags. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should use **1-** `aTag.Attributes["href"].Value` instead of `aTag.InnerHtml`. **2-**  `+` instead of `+=` in *DownloadFile*

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have solved this by using a different approach. I imported the html into a datatable, I then iterated through the table, selecting the filenames and appending to a fixed url.

Comment: @TAR can you post your solution as an answer and accept it as a valid answer ? thanks